# Right context for Toast in Activity called from service?

Tags: android, android-service, toast

I got the following method within my Main Activity

```
public void showMessages(int MSGCODE) {
    Log.d("MSG", "showmessage reached with code " + MSGCODE);
    switch (MSGCODE) 
    { 
      case '0': 
        Toast.makeText(tabHost.getContext(), "Account verification failed. Please try to reenter your password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        break; 
      case '1': 
        Toast.makeText(tabHost.getContext(), "Networking Service started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break; 
      case '2': 
        Toast.makeText(tabHost.getContext(), "Networking Service stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        break; 
      case '3': 
        Toast.makeText(tabHost.getContext(), "Connection to server failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break; 
    }
}
```

In a service i invoke the method like this:

```
MAIN_ACTIVITY.showMessages(Consts.CONNECTION_FAILED);
```

But there is no toast showing up. The TabHost is hosting three different tabs. I already got the idea, that its propably the wrong context i pick, but i didnt got any idea which one is the right one and how to get it.

```
private TabHost tabHost;
private final String[] loginStrings = new String[2];

public static Boolean runOnce = true;
public static ArrayList<String> messages;
private Intent svc;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BuddylistActivity.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tabBuddylist").setIndicator("Buddylist").setContent(intent));
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ChatsActivity.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tabBuddylist").setIndicator("Chats").setContent(intent));
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SchedularActivity.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tabBuddylist").setIndicator("Schedular").setContent(intent));
```

Answer (score 2):

try making `showMessages()` static and pass Context as parameter.

```
public static void showMessages(Context context, int MSGCODE)
```

You can show your Toast messages like

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Networking Service started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and invoking this method from service you can simply pass `this` as Context:

```
MAIN_ACTIVITY.showMessages(this, Consts.CONNECTION_FAILED);
```

This way your Toasts will show even if Activity itself was destroyed.

You can keep your original (`non-static` method) and implement it like

```
public void showMessages(int MSGCODE){
     showMessages(this, MSGCODE); //calls static method with current context
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection to server failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I make toast messages,

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contetx, Message, Duraction);
toast.show(); //This being the part that is missing
```

I could be completely wrong, but I always use the toast.show() method to actually get it to display